# How to repaint a jpanel every x seconds?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jpanel

i would like to know how to repaint and update the background of a JPanel every x seconds...This is my code:

```
package view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final JLabel score;
private final static String[] BACKGROUND_COLORS = {"black", "blue", "darkpurple", "purple"};
private int i = 0;

public GamePanel() {
    this.score = new JLabel("Score: ");
    this.score.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 20);
    this.score.setOpaque(false);
    this.score.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    this.add(score);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //Image background = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/" + BACKGROUND_COLORS[i] + "Background.png")).getImage();
    //g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Image background = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/" + BACKGROUND_COLORS[i] + "Background.png")).getImage();
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
            System.out.println("trying my timer");
            i++;
            if (i == 4) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}
}
```

I have 2 issues with this code:
1- The JPanel doesn't get painted at all.
2- The first print is ok, then the the number of prints is doubled each time.
Any suggestion? Thank you in advance

UPDATE: I solved the problem in this way:

```
package view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final JLabel score;
private int i = 0;
private final static String[] BACKGROUND_COLORS = {"black", "blue", "darkpurple", "purple"};
private final static int DELAY = 10000;

public GamePanel() {
    this.score = new JLabel("Score: ");
    this.score.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 20);
    this.score.setOpaque(false);
    this.score.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    this.add(score);
    Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            i++;
            if (i == 4) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Image background = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/" + BACKGROUND_COLORS[this.i] + "Background.png")).getImage();
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

UPDATE 2:

```
package view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final JLabel score;
private int currentImage;
private final List<Image> backgrounds = new ArrayList<>();
private static final String[] BACKGROUND_COLORS = {"black", "blue", "darkpurple", "purple"};
private static final int DELAY = 1000;

public GamePanel() {
    super();
    this.score = new JLabel("Score: ");
    this.score.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 20);
    this.score.setOpaque(false);
    this.score.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    this.add(score);
    for (final String s : BACKGROUND_COLORS) {
        backgrounds.add(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/" + s + "Background.png")).getImage());
    }
    final Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
            currentImage++;
            if (currentImage == BACKGROUND_COLORS.length) {
                currentImage = 0;
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(backgrounds.get(this.currentImage), 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: Take that `Timer` out of the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.

Comment: Show us your `main` method.

Comment: `I solved the problem in this way:` - No, that is wrong! Never use revalidate() or repaint() in a painting method. The repaint() will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Also, you should not be reading the images in the painting method. You should create an array/List of images when you create the class. The painting method should only paint the appropriate image.

Comment: I need `repaint()` to ensure that the change is applied to the background. Do you guys know some better ways?

Comment: should i call the `repaint()` inside the `ActionPerformed` method?

Comment: `should i call the repaint() inside the ActionPerformed method?` - that is what Masud suggested and you accepted that answer, so why did you not implement the answer as given?

Comment: you're gooddamn right guys, my apologies, I have updated my solution in UPDATE 2 of my first post

Comment: Thank you. Reversed vote from -1 to +1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html),

```
class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

 Timer timer=new Timer(1000, this);

 public GamePanel() {
   timer.start();// Start the timer here.
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
    if(ev.getSource()==timer){
      repaint();// this will call at every 1 second
    }

}
```