# How to make an interface implement runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create an interface that when implemented, anything inside the method will be continually executed on a separate thread.

Hopefully, this description makes sense, here is the idea.

Interface:

```
public interface Painting {

void onPaint();
}
```

Thread:

```
public class Paintable implements Runnable, Painting {

@Override
public void run() {
    onPaint();
}

@Override
public void onPaint() {
}
}
```

Lastly, the goal is you'd implement Painting which would require you to implement and override the onPaint method. Then whatever you decide to put in the method would be ran on the Paintable Thread when that thread is executed.

```
public class Main implements Painting {

private static final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Paintable(), 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

@Override
public void onPaint() {
System.out.println("This text should be continously printed, but is not.");
}
}
```

Comment: Looks okay to me, what is the error?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Issue: For example, I have the Paintable thread being executed in a pool continually. If I implement Painting then for example if I print random text, the text isn't being printed like it should.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072796/how-to-repaint-a-jpanel-every-x-seconds or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377509/repainting-continuously-in-java didn't give a solution?

Comment: You make `Paintable` `Runnable` via `interface Paintable extends Runnable`, but that doesn't seem to have anything to do with your actual question, whatever it is.

Comment: What text? Printed where? Show a [mcve] please

Comment: Well, you're passing a new Paintable to your executor. Paintable has a default implementation of onPaint() that does absolutely nothing. If you want your main class's onPaint() to be called, then it should extend Paintable and you should pass `new Main()` to your executor. But you really don't need this Paintable class and Painting interface. Just use a lambda: `Main main = new Main(); executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> main.onPaint(), ...)`.

Comment: If I make the main class extend Paintable that would mean I'd have to make Paintable an abstract class. My goal is to have the main class implement Painting to require them to override the onPaint method.

Comment: No, you don't need it to be abstract, but anyway. If your goal is what you say, then you shouldn't use inheritance. Define a PaintingRunnable class that implements Runnable, takes a Painting as argument of its constructor, and have its run() method call the painting's onPaint() method. Then use `scheduleAtFixedRate(new PaintingRunnable(new Main()), ...)`. But, again, this is overkill, given that a Runnable delegating to another object's method can be implemented in a single line of code with a lambda.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean JB Nizet when you say take Painting as an argument and then have it's run() method call the paintings onPaint() method.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you have a Painting interface, and want to transform it into a Runnable that calls onPaint().

You can do this:

```
public class PaintingRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Painting painting;

    public PaintingRunnable(Painting painting) {
        this.painting = painting;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.painting.onPaint();
    }
}
```

And you can thus make a Runnable out of a painting using

```
Runnable runnableThatCallsOnPaint = new PaintingRunnable(somePainting);
```

But this is overkill, since you can do the exact same thing without any class using a lambda:

```
Runnable runnableThatCallsOnPaint = () -> somePaining.onPaint()
```

You can even just use a method reference:

```
Runnable runnableThatCallsOnPaint = somePaining::onPaint
```

Comment: I don't believe this would work for what I'm trying to do. I want this interface to be easily implementable. For example, let's say I just created a brand new class. I should be able to JUST have the following and it should work in theory.

`public class Test implements Painting {

    @Override
    public void onPaint() {
        System.out.println("This should run");
    }

}
`

Comment: So, once you have created that class, you need an instance of that class right? So you create one: `Test test = new Test();`. And nw you want to execute the test's onPaint() method using an executor, right? So you create a Runnable out of `test`, and pass it to the executor: `executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(test::onPaint, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`. That's all you need. Not sure why it wouldn't work, and how it doesn't fit your needs. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: That is what I don't want to do. I'm trying to write this in a manner where I wouldn't have to create an instance of it. Yes I've tested your method and it does work, but system I'm developing wouldn't allow the user create an instance of it in which they could only implement Painting for it to work.

Comment: That's impossible. You can't call an instance method (onPaint), without an instance of the class defining that instance method. Just like, you can't drive a car if you don't have a car.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in above answer I am agree with that .You have to create a template class that defined the your step and on each step what will execute you have to defined by subclass or a delegate to your class which will execute exact logic.

Main class:

```
 public class Main implements Painting {

        private static final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Paintable(new Main()), 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPaint() {
            System.out.println("This text should be continously printed, but is not.");
        }
    }
```

paintable driver class

```
public class Paintable implements Runnable {

    private final Painting painting;

    public Paintable(Painting painting) {
        this.painting = painting;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        painting.onPaint();
    }

}
```