# Java Canvas has low fps if mouse is stationary

Tags: java, canvas, graphics, java-canvas

If I'm not somehow updating the screen, several calls to `canvas.repaint()` seem to be just skipped altogether. While moving the mouse, everything works great.

My code is as follows:

```
package yeet.gfxTut;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Toot extends Canvas {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int xPos, yPos, yV, xV;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Random rand = new Random();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Drawing");
        Canvas canvas = new Toot();
        canvas.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        canvas.addMouseListener(new Toot().new TootMListener());
        xPos = rand.nextInt(400);
        yPos = rand.nextInt(400);
        xV = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        yV = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000 / 60);
            canvas.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        if (xPos < 0) {
            xV += rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
            xV = 0 - xV;
        }
        if (yPos < 0) {
            yV += rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
            yV = 0 - yV;
        }
        if (xPos > 400) {
            xV += rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
            xV = 0 - xV;
        }
        if (yPos > 400) {
            yV += rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
            yV = 0 - yV;
        }
        xPos += xV;
        yPos += yV;
        g.fillOval(xPos, yPos, 6, 6);
    }

    private class TootMListener implements MouseListener {
        Random rand = new Random();

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            xV = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
            yV = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }

    }
}
```

I've had this issue on multiple different `canvas` projects, any help?

UPDATE: I tried to use the suggested answer, and it resulted in the same issue. New code is as follows:

```
package yeet.gfxTut;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Toot extends Canvas implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int xPos, yPos, yV, xV;

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000/60, this);
    public Toot() {
        super();
        timer.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // timer.start();
        Random rand = new Random();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Drawing");
        Canvas canvas = new Toot();
        canvas.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        canvas.addMouseListener(new Toot().new TootMListener());
        xPos = rand.nextInt(400);
        yPos = rand.nextInt(400);
        xV = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        yV = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000 / 60);
            canvas.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        if (xPos < 0) {
            xV += rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
            xV = 0 - xV;
        }
        if (yPos < 0) {
            yV += rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
            yV = 0 - yV;
        }
        if (xPos > 400) {
            xV += rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
            xV = 0 - xV;
        }
        if (yPos > 400) {
            yV += rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
            yV = 0 - yV;
        }
        xPos += xV;
        yPos += yV;
        g.fillOval(xPos, yPos, 6, 6);
    }

    private class TootMListener implements MouseListener {
        Random rand = new Random();

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            xV = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
            yV = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // if(e.getSource() == timer){
            repaint();
        // }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to repaint a jpanel every x seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072796/how-to-repaint-a-jpanel-every-x-seconds)

Comment: @Sascha Nope, tried that answer, but I couldn't get it to work. New update shows the code I tried.

Comment: You still try to update your Component outside of the event-dispatch thread. Did you really try the [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the first code, instead of

```java
while (true) {
    Thread.sleep(1000 / 60);
    canvas.repaint();
}
```

use the `Timer` in the Swing package:

```java
new javax.swing.Timer(1000/60,event->canvas.repaint()).start();
```

I have taken your class and it runs smooth as expected:

```java
public class Toot extends Canvas {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int xPos, yPos, yV, xV;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Random rand = new Random();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Drawing");
        Canvas canvas = new Toot();
        canvas.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                xV = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
                yV = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
            }
        });
        xPos = rand.nextInt(400);
        yPos = rand.nextInt(400);
        xV = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        yV = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        new javax.swing.Timer(1000/60,e->canvas.repaint()).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        if (xPos < 0) {
            xV += rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
            xV = Math.abs(xV);
        }
        if (yPos < 0) {
            yV += rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
            yV = Math.abs(yV);
        }
        if (xPos > 400) {
            xV += rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
            xV = - Math.abs(xV);
        }
        if (yPos > 400) {
            yV += rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
            yV = - Math.abs(yV);
        }
        xPos +=xV;
        yPos +=yV;
        g.fillOval(xPos, yPos, 6, 6);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this at the bottom of the main() method, both `new javax.swing.Timer(1000/60,event->canvas.repaint());` and `new javax.swing.Timer(1000/60,event->canvas.repaint()).start();` and neither worked. (also deleted the while(true) bit, sorry about being dumb)

Comment: I have added the complete class. Try it.

Comment: Using your exact code (+ imports and package declaration) still causes the issue, but now it loops around the edges instead of bouncing, still at a low frame rate unless mouse is moving. Could this be an OS issue?

Comment: The modulo operation for looping I had done because your code doesn't prevent the "dot" from leaving the frame. (That you will have to work on too.) If you still have a low frame rate (it should be around 16 fps ) then the reason has to be something else, OS or hardware or such.

Comment: I do get a good 60 fps when I move my mouse around, so it's not an issue with hardware, but thanks for the help. My code tried to make the ball bounce unpredictably by detecting when the ball is off the screen in the x direction, and reversing it's x velocity, same with the y direction. Any reason this wouldn't work?

Comment: Your assumption if the values of xV and yV where correctly greater or lesser than zero were wrong due to the randomness. I edited my code to safely set the correct sign.